# How can i compare a variable value from prompt() to all elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried this...

```
var age = prompt("your age");
var myArray = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
if (age == myArray) {
   alert("we know your age");
else {
   alert("new age added");
```

I want to compare the     prompt()     value to the list in the array

Comment: You want to check it is present in `array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some to iterate through `myArray` and check if any of the element is same as input given by user.

```js
var age = prompt("your age");
var myArray = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
if (myArray.some(e=> e == age)) {
   alert("we know your age");
} else {
   alert("new age added"); 
}
```

Comment: Why not use find here?

Comment: @LucaKiebel yes you can use. but here in return we want true or false. find returns the matched element that will implicitly changes to true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Use `includes` method to check if age is already in the array or not. Includes check if a given variable present in the array or not.

```js
var age = prompt("your age");
var myArray = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
if (myArray.includes(Number(age))) {
   alert("we know your age");
   }
else {
   alert("new age added");  
   }
```

You can also use `indexOf` method to find the index of the variable in the array. If it is not present, it will output -1

```js
var age = prompt("your age");
var myArray = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
if (myArray.indexOf(Number(age))!=-1) {
   alert("we know your age");
   }
else {
   alert("new age added");  
   }
```

Comment: Just for the sake of adding useful infos, beware of IE, which lacks the support for `Array.prototype.includes`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I worked this way

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)** which `Boolean`. And you also need to `parseInt()` `age`
And try to avoid creating Array like this. Use `[]`

```js
var age = parseInt(prompt("your age"));
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
if (myArray.includes(age)) {
   alert("we know your age");
   }
else {
   alert("new age added"); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the age is included in the array, **you can use `includes`**, don't forget to **parse the input to a number** if it is a string, you can do this with `parseInt`, `Number` or by prepending a `+` in front of the string:

```js
const age = prompt('your age');
const myArray = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
if (myArray.includes(Number(age))) {
   alert('we know your age');
} else {
   alert('new age added');
}
```